# How to copy and paste code without rich text formatting?

Tags: editor, copy-paste

I used to often find myself coping a piece of code from a website/Word document etc only to discover that when doing Paste I would end up with the desired code plus some extra HTML tags/text, basically extra formatting information.

To get rid of that extra ballast I would paste the text to the Notepad and then copy it again and then paste to the desired destination.

Pretty recently I discovered a simple and free tool for Windows called [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) that allows me to cut the Notepad step. It basically adds an extra keyboard shortcut e.g WinKey + V that will do the Paste action without formatting; just pure text. 
I find it very handy.

I was wondering what approach would you use yourselves? Are they any better/easier to use tools around?

Comment: I love PureText - it's what I use and I had no problem getting used to it.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + V on Windows

Comment: Shameless plug, command-line friendly pasting: https://github.com/postprintum/devcomrade

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Just to summarize the available options:**

**Tools**

- [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) - free tool for Windows
- Use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and write your own macro
  as suggested by [Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/#132826)

**Browsers**

- To **copy** plain text from a browser: [Copy As Plain Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-as-plain-text) or [CopyPlainText](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/134?id=134&vid=654) (suggested by [cori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/#122416)) - Firefox extensions
- To **paste** without formatting to a browser (Firefox/Chrome at least): <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows/Linux, see below for Mac OS X.

**Other**

- [Under **Mac OS X**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343), you can <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste  with the "current" format (*Edit* -> *Paste and Match Style*); or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste without formatting (by [Kamafeather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/#comment81395440_122475))
- Paste to Notepad (or other text editor), and then copy from Notepad and paste again
- For single-line text: paste to any non-rich text field (browser URL, textarea, search/find inputs, etc.)

**Please feel free to edit/add new items**

Comment: @Sterex that should also work on Mac, too.

Comment: If you are using Firefox with its **Adblock Plus** add-on then you might notice CTRL+SHIFT+V does not paste as plain text but it opens up a "Blockable items on current page" dialog at the lower bottom of the page. To fix this type `about:config` in the address bar and change the value of `extensions.adblockplus.sidebar_key` to `Accel Shift U` and restart Firefox.

Comment: On OSX you only need cmd-shift-v

Answer (score 33):

Just for reference, under Mac OS X, you can use <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste without formatting or with the "current" format.

Note: in some apps it's <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (see "Edit" Menu → "Paste and Match Style")

Comment: quad-bucky-cokebottle...

Comment: does not work inside Google Docs

Comment: @gdelfino: works for me, both in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: does not work in for instance the Mail.app, which is where I need it the most. I usually resort to pasting into the subject field, and then copying the result...

Comment: It does work for me in Mail.app.

Comment: In Mail.app, use `⌘+⇧ T` (command-shift-t) to turn all formatted text into plain text. Also available from the Format menu.

Comment: This does not work for me under OS X 10.9.5. The previous answer of Command + Shift + Option + V does work to remove formatting while pasting

Comment: ```⌘-Command``` + ```⇧-Shift``` + ```V``` is enough.

Comment: this does not work in Safari on macos (v17.3 on Sonoma 14.3) ie there is no way to paste plain text and my composition of rich text with white color gets sent in an email unintentionally so when I see it in sent mail it's illegible (and the recipient must be less than impressed about my technical skills)...one of so many reasons I (increasingly) struggle to appreciate Apple software over the past decade

Answer (score 23):

I'm a big fan of [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com.).
I defined a 'paste plain text' macro that works in any application. It runs when I press Ctrl+Shift+V and pastes a plain version of whatever is on the clipboard.  The nice thing about Autohotkey: you can code things to work the way you want them to work across all applications.

```
^+v::
    ; Convert any copied files, HTML, or other formatted text to plain text
    Clipboard = %Clipboard%

    ; Paste by pressing Ctrl+V
    SendInput, ^v
return
```

Comment: Been a fan of AHK for yeeeaaarrrsss... even botted a few games way back in the day with it!

Comment: this is f*cking useful :))))

Answer (score 10):

From websites, using Firefox, I use the [CopyPlainText](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/134?id=134&vid=654) extension.

Comment: Very handy extension - if it could be bowled together with AutoCopy (and made to work in FF3!) it'd be great.

Comment: Thank you cori!  I was always aggrivated by this, the extension works great!

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty useful thing ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you're pasting into Word you can use the Paste Special command.

Answer (score 2):

I have [**Far.exe**](http://www.farmanager.com/?l=en) as the first item in the start menu.

Richtext in the clipboard ->

```
ctrl-escape,arrdown,enter,shift-f4,$,enter
shift-insert,ctrl-insert,alt-backspace,
f10,enter
```

-> plaintext in the clipboard

Pros: no mouse, just blind typing, ends exactly where i was before

Cons: ANSI encoding - international symbols are lost

Luckily, I do not have to do that too often :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice find with your PureText. I had build, before I change keyboard, a key that was running a macro that was copying-pasting-copying in notepad for this task! I'll give a try to your software since I do not have any macro key now :(

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an unpublished java app to monitor the clipboard, replacing items that offered text along with other richer formats, with items only offering the plain text format.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a little clipboard icon that pops up at the end of the material you pasted.  Click on this and choose "keep text only".

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenOffice.org and that offers a paste special option, where you can omit the formatting altogether. If you are not bound to MS Word, it's IMO worth a try and it's free :-)

Comment: If only MS Word has such a feature :)

Comment: MS Word has it's feature called "Special Paste" well in french version is "Collage spécial"

Comment: @hometoast if only MS Word was free...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever these plugins and options aren't available I just use my good ol friend notepad.  Paste content into notepad where it won't accept the extra formatting and then copy it right back out. Sort of hacky but oh well. It works!

Comment: OP was asking for better/easier tools than the one suggested [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/#122599) that s/he moved on from for the reasons that brought his/her question.

Answer (score 0):

I usually work with Notepad2, all the text I copy from the web are pasted there and then reused, that allows me to clean it (from format and make modifications).

[You can download Notepad2 here](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Word then try ALT+E, S, U, Enter (Uses the Paste Special)