# How to create code box without rich text formatting

Tags: powerpoint, plaintext, richtext

My question is related to this topic [How to copy and paste code without rich text formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/how-to-copy-and-paste-code-without-rich-text-formatting) except its from the opposite viewpoint: I'm creating a document from PowerPoint in which I have code snippets in text boxes. I want to make the document as simple as possible by making the code snippet text boxes easy to copy and paste the code into a terminal to run without editing anything. However, the way I have it right now is that when I copy and paste it keeps the formatting and I have to go though letter by letter to erase the end of line symbols. How should I format this in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake was not realizing that PowerPoint auto formats hyphens and quotation marks to make them stylized, and the terminal was not recognizing the symbols. All I did was type in a quotation mark/hyphen then copying that before I pressed the space bar after it to save the original formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of most formatting by copy/pasting from PPT to Notepad and then copy/pasting from there to your terminal program, or if the latter has a Paste Special command, you should be able to paste as plain text, which'd get rid of formatting.

Line/Paragraph breaks are another matter.  If the end of line symbols are the only formatting problem when you've pasted the text into a terminal (emulator program, I assume), it sounds as though the terminal's using CR or LF as a line ending, whereas PPT's using CR/LF pairs.  It might only be necessary to reconfigure the terminal software to use CR/LF.

It's worth a look at this page on my site, where I explain what line and paragraph ending characters are used by different versions of PowerPoint in different situations.

Paragraph endings and line breaks
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I just realized I made a mistake in thinking it was the line breaks that were causing weird copy/paste issues: it was actually because PowerPoint automatically changed straight quotation marks to curved quotation marks, and the terminal can't recognize the latter. It also did the same for hyphens- it auto-formatted to longer width hyphens.