# How to remove specific HTML tags in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, tags

I need to copy/paste text from Microsoft Powerpoint to Visual studio 2010's aspx page. When I copy the text it copies several unwanted tags (like style tags, span, p tag etc.). How can I cleanup that copied text in Visual Studio? I have also installed Resharper, is it useful in removing unwanted tags? For example I want to remove all style tags from a document or want to remove all span tags. I want to cleanup/remove unwanted tags in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

After you have already pasted the text, it will be pretty hard to automatically determine between unwanted and actual tags, perhaps a complicated Replace All with Regex would work. But there are ways to copy/paste pure text, look here: [How to copy and paste code without rich text formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122404/how-to-copy-and-paste-code-without-rich-text-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is now easy way to remove specific HTML tags. I would suggest you to use find and replace feature of Notepad++ where you can easily write a regular expression to replace tags. Also, I would suggest you to use these links to clean up your HTML
[WordToHTML](https://wordhtml.com/) [CleanHTML](https://word2cleanhtml.com/). I hope this helps you to resolve a part of your concern.